# QGIS 3.22.16 Layout: how the Atlas displays only one ID at the time on the map

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, layouts, dissolve, atlas

[image]I am using QGIS 3.22.16. My goal is to create maps for each Tree ID. I used the Atlas tool and dissolved the tree layer. However, the atlas shows several ID trees on the same map (like Atlas image). [image]Is there a way to filter by Tree ID so I can have maps for each Tree ID? (like Atlas_2 image)

Comment: you are referencing 2 images in your question, but the is only one attached...can you edit your question again?

Comment: Have you tried using a rule based symbology and using a filter in the rules like 
$id  =  @atlas_featureid

Comment: I added the other image. I used the rule based symbology and filtered $"TreeID"=@atlas_featureid. The points are not longer on the map. Maybe the $ is not in the right place.

Comment: It could be  "TreeID"=@atlas_featureid OR $id = @atlas_featureid not a mix of both. As a side note be avare that filtering on atlas mean that your feature won't be visible on the main canvas when the atlas is not activated (ie. when the layout is closed...)

Comment: If your question is also about having one map per *tree* you need to run your atlas based on your tree layer without dissolving it. Then it will zoom in and focus on one tree feature at a time.